Python scrapy playwright getting error ValueError: Page.evaluate: The future belongs to a different loop
here is full error logs
line 514, in wrap_api_call
    raise rewrite_error(error, f"{parsed_st['apiName']}: {error}") from None
ValueError: Page.evaluate: The future belongs to a different loop than the one specified as the loop argument

I am trying to click on submit button after get captcha response from api. my full code
import scrapy
from anticaptchaofficial.recaptchav2proxyless import recaptchaV2Proxyless
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

class RecaptchaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "recaptcha_spider"
    start_urls = ["https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo"]
    delay_after_submit = 5  # Time in seconds to wait after submit

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url,
                dont_filter=True,
                meta={
                    "playwright": True,
                    "playwright_include_page": True,
                },
                callback=self.solve_captcha,
            )

    async def solve_captcha(self, response):
        # Step 1: Solve the CAPTCHA using AntiCaptcha API
        api_key = "my api key"  # Replace with your actual API key
        solver = recaptchaV2Proxyless()
        solver.set_key(api_key)
        solver.set_website_url(response.url)
        solver.set_website_key("6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-")  # Replace with Google reCAPTCHA site key

        captcha_solution = solver.solve_and_return_solution()
        if captcha_solution:
            self.logger.info(f"Solved CAPTCHA: {captcha_solution}")
            
            # Step 2: Execute JavaScript to fill the CAPTCHA solution and click the submit button
            page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
            await page.evaluate(f'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "{captcha_solution}";')  # Replace with the correct ID if different
            await page.click("button[type='submit']")  # Replace with the correct selector for the submit button
            
            # Wait for the next page or any other action you want to perform
            await page.wait_for_timeout(self.delay_after_submit)
            
            # Step 3: Handle the next step after clicking submit (if necessary)
            # You might want to retrieve the new page content here
            new_content = await page.content()
            self.logger.info("New page content after submit:")
            self.logger.info(new_content)
        else:
            self.logger.error("Failed to solve CAPTCHA.")


I was also getting this error, which I believe was due to running scrapy with scrapy-playwright on a Windows machine. The scrapy-playwright documentation indicates that on Windows, scrapy and playwright have to run in different loops. My solution to this error was to run my code in a docker container which seems to have worked.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
